How to use IEEEbiographynophoto in ieeeaccess.cls?
I am using the ieeeaccess.cls, (which also uses IEEEtran.cls). I want to delete the photo of one of the authors. When using the begin{IEEEbiography} command and deleting the photo, it still puts an empty space for the photo. I saw there is a IEEEbiographynophoto command in the class. However, when trying to use it the document stops compiling. . I need to know how to use this option please.
Thank you.

Hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing code, but I think note this answer, IEEEbiographynophoto is an environment to be used in place of the IEEEbiography environment.

I am just doing exactly what is stated in the link you shared. When I use the IEEEbiographynophoto, it simply stops compiling. I have not touched the ieeeaccess.cls, nor the IEEEtran.cls. I see there is a definition for the IEEEbiographynophoto environment, but when I try to call it, it does not recognize it. Do you think it would be useful to read the class codes?
\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{Prof.\ Quack}
Prof.\ van Quack is an esteemed scientist at the University of Quackland, but she does not get a picture. \lipsum[1]
\end{IEEEbiographynophoto}
\end{document}
